# Turn a Vector<HashMap<String, String>> Into a String or a JSON Object

Tags: rust

I have the following variable:

```
let mut responseVector: Vec<HashMap<String, String>> = Vec::new();
```

I need to send that via http... the output of that looks like this at the moment.

```
[{"username": "Mario", "password": "itzzami", "email": "mario@bortherco.com"}, {"username": "Luigi", "password": "ayayayay", "email": "luigi@bortherco.com"}]
```

So any way to make that a string or a JSON object works (preferably directly a JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck, [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) provides exactly the sort of magic you are looking for with [`serde_json::to_string`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_string.html) and [`serde_json::from_str`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_str.html).

```rust
let mut responseVector: Vec<HashMap<String, String>> = Vec::new();

// serde_json::to_string will do all the work for us
let json: String = serde_json::to_string(&responseVector).unwrap();

println!("{:?}", json);
```

You can also derive `serde::Serialize` and `serde::Deserialize` for a struct  so you do not need to deal with getting values out of a hashmap.

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct LoginInfo {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
}

let response = r#"[{"username": "Mario", "password": "itzzami", "email": "mario@bortherco.com"}, {"username": "Luigi", "password": "ayayayay", "email": "luigi@bortherco.com"}]"#;

// We can also deserialize a struct which implements Deserialize.
let requests: Vec<LoginInfo> = serde_json::from_str(response).unwrap();

println!("Received {} requests!", requests.len());
for request in requests {
    println!("{:?}", request);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3103f6dc7b420d618064887373ed3786)

Comment: Let's   try it!  ..

Comment: No way, I tried using the serde_json method yesterday but did not work lol... your implementation did lol thanks! I can accept it in two minutes.